# How to find absolute value in matrix in C?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I'm doing a C program to solve a system of linear equations by fixed point iteration method. And I have to check if the main matrix is diagonally dominant. But when I enter abs and element of the matrix, it says

Error (active)  E0308   more than one instance of overloaded function "abs" matches the argument list.

- How can I fix this?

```
//for every row
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
    //for every column finds the sum of the row
                double sum = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
                    sum += abs(k[i][j]);
                sum -= abs(k[i][i]);
    //check
                if (abs(k[i][i]) < sum) {
                    printf("The matrix is not diagonally dominant.");
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the type of `k`?  The full error message should show you the function candidates causing the ambiguity.  Are you actually using a C++ compiler for this C program?  In C, the correct function is `fabs`.  Also, in C there is no such thing as overloaded functions.

Comment: With a C++ compiler you might have ambiguity with the C function `abs` which operates on integers, and the C++ standard library function `std::abs` which has overloads for integer and floating point types.  If you are mixing C and C++ code and doing other things like importing the entire `std` namespace, be aware that this can cause problems strikingly similar to what you describe.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I really didn't know that fabs is correct. I just saw abs() function in <math.h> library. Thank you : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int abs(int)` is for `int`.

Use `double fabs(double)` with `double`s.